# C++ do we need mutex when using map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, mutex

I have two threads, one is inserting and another is deleting an entry in the map. I am wondering whether I have a mutex around these function calls? And also one thread incrementing a counter inside this map and the other decrementing that counter. Do I need mutex for that as well?

Thanks,

Comment: If two threads both make changes to the same data, then you need to protect that data against races.

Comment: Simple answer is Yes. You need to provide for synchronization. STL containers are not thread safe.

Comment: For example the following requires mutex; 1) std::map<int, obj *>::iterator it2 = mymap.find(val); 2)mymap.erase (it2);mymap.insert( std::pair<int,obj *>(val, obj)); but the following does not; myobj= it2->second; it2->second->ctr++;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes to the map itself (insertions, deletions) need to be synchronized. The same is true for traversal and lookup (i.e. `begin()`, `find()`, `[]`, etc.).

Multiple threads can access different *elements* safely, though.

Comment: How about find function ? One of the threads is using find function of the map, do I need mutex aroung find function as well?

Comment: @AvbAvb: Yes, lookup also needs to be synchronised. You can't have one thread traversing the map while another one changes it. So you should get iterators or references while guarded by a mutex, but you can change the content of the elements (provided you guarantee they won't be deleted) outside the lock.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. How about begin function?

Comment: Put differently, you can have multiple concurrent readers as long as there are no concurrent writes happening.

Comment: @ipmcc: No, that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Any const function will be fine for concurrent access from multiple threads.

Comment: @AvbAvb: *Any* kind of lookup. That includes `find`, `begin`, anything.

Comment: @ipmcc: No, please stop saying that. You can't safely call `cbegin` in one thread while another thread inserts an element into the map.

Comment: That's *exactly* what I said. You can safely call `cbegin` from multiple threads simultaneously as long as there are no threads calling non-const methods at the same time.

Comment: Another question is for example one thread get the interator of the map and increments a variable that is not used by the other thread. I mean that variable is only used by one thread. Do I need mutex for incrementing that variable as well?

Comment: @AvbAvb: No, that's what I said: once you have the iterator or reference, and you can guarantee that you're the only thread to do so, and you can guarantee that nobody will delete the element, you don't need to synchronise access to the *element*.

Comment: For example the following requires mutex; 1) std::map<int, obj *>::iterator it2 = mymap.find(val); 2)mymap.erase (it2);mymap.insert( std::pair<int,obj *>(val, obj)); but the following does not; myobj= it2->second; it2->second->ctr++;

Answer (score 0):

If you are incrementing and decrementing the SAME element in the `map` (or what may be the same element and you can't say for sure), then you need to have some sort of synchronisation. You could use an `std::atomic<int>` to avoid having to use a `mutex` tho'.

Any insert or remove in the tree will need to be protected with a `mutex` or similar - and of course, that also means that any access to the content of the tree needs to be protected in the same way, so if you use `std::map<T>::iterator` (at least for `erase` in the tree) will be invalidated. So you really need to ensure that no `erase` happens when you use any other access to the tree. This includes "ready-made" functions such as `find`.

Comment: For example the following requires mutex; 1) std::map<int, obj *>::iterator it2 = mymap.find(val); 2)mymap.erase (it2);mymap.insert( std::pair<int,obj *>(val, obj)); but the following does not; myobj= it2->second; it2->second->ctr++;

Comment: As long as you know that the object referred by `it2` is not being erased at the same time as you are using it (and that no other thread is doing `it2-ctr++`), then: yes.